# Syntax Error while comparison values from different tables

Tags: c#, sql, database, count, oledb

I'm getting a "syntax error" while using the code below.
it suppoused to avoid adding row when you entered all the values of this specific protein(it is a project combined Biology and Programming.
'serialPro' is a textbox which contains a number,but saved as string.
'Reset_Click'  resetes all textboxes.
THE CODE:

```
            if ((serialPro.Text == String.Empty) || (codon1.Text == String.Empty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You didn't fill all the fields","Attention"
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            Reset_Click(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {

            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            myConnection.Open();

            string mySQL = " SELECT COUNT(tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro) AS orderAASerialPro1 FROM tblOrderAA" +
                             "WHERE tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro=" + Convert.ToInt32(serialPro.Text) +
                             " SELECT (tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum) FROM tblProInfo WHERE tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum=" +
                             Convert.ToInt32(serialPro.Text);
            OleDbCommand datacommand = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

            OleDbDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();
            dataReader.Read();
            if (dataReader.GetInt32(0) == dataReader.GetInt32(1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have entered all the amino acids for this protein", "Attention",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                Reset_Click(sender, e);
            }
```

TNX for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the way you have it setup, even if it were supported by access, would require you to process different resultset (you would have to call Reader.NextResult in order to get the values from the second select statement.

However, this is an easy problem to solve: break your queries up into separate commands and just get the one value from each query that you are looking for:

```
        int TotalCompleted;
        int TotalToComplete;

        string mySQL;
        OleDbCommand datacommand;
        object oValue;

        mySQL = " SELECT COUNT(tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro) AS orderAASerialPro1 FROM tblOrderAA WHERE tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro=" + Convert.ToInt32(serialPro.Text);
        datacommand = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

        oValue = datacommand.ExecuteScalar();
        if (oValue != DBNull.Value)
        {
            TotalCompleted = (int)oValue;
        } else 
        {
            TotalCompleted = 0;
        }

        mySQL = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo WHERE tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum=" + Convert.ToInt32(serialPro.Text);
        datacommand = new OleDbCommand(mySQL, myConnection);

        oValue = datacommand.ExecuteScalar();
        if (oValue != DBNull.Value)
        {
            TotalToComplete = (int)oValue;
        } else 
        {
            TotalToComplete = 0;
        }

        if (TotalCompleted == TotalToComplete)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered all the amino acids for this protein", "Attention",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            Reset_Click(sender, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if having two select statements in your MySQL query is valid or not, or why you're taking a string only to turn it into a number so you can add it to another string, but this is probably the cause of the syntax error.

```
" SELECT COUNT(tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro) AS orderAASerialPro1 FROM tblOrderAA" +
"WHERE tblOrderAA.orderAASerialPro=" + Convert.ToInt32(serialPro.Text) +
```

The way you're concatenating this string means there would be no space between `tblOrderAA` and `WHERE`. Add a space in between.

You should also look up SQL injection/parameterized queries.

Comment: so how can i put 2 statements in one string?each one works if its the only statement.